# Microsoft Graph .NET SDK - Retrieving ListItem Field

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to retrieve the items from a list in a SharePoint subsite with the .NET SDK. I can get the subsite, list, and items, but I don't know how to retrieve the columns. For example, here I'm trying to list all the titles of each list item:

```
IListItemsCollectionPage items = await graphClient
    .Sites[targetstate_id]
    .Lists[targetlist_id]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .Select("Fields")
    .GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Chosen ID: " + lists[listindex].Id);
Console.WriteLine("Number of items: " + items.Count);
for (var index = 0; index < items.Count; index++) {
    //(attempting) at writing the title of each item in list
    Console.WriteLine("Title " + items[index].Fields.AdditionalData["Title"]);
}
Console.WriteLine("Completed");
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fields` property of a `ListItem` is a collection that you need to "expand" rather than "select".

The code you're using here is executing the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items?$select=fields
```

What you want however is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id}/lists/{id}/items?$expand=fields
```

When using the SDK, you'll want something like this:

```
IListItemsCollectionPage items = await graphClient
    .Sites[targetstate_id]
    .Lists[targetlist_id]
    .Items
    .Request()
    .Expand("fields")
    .GetAsync();
```